# Hide status bar on screen rotation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to hide the status bar on screen rotation events in `Windows Phone 8.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows the status bar on `Portrait` orientation, and hides it on `Landscape` orientation.

First you need to subscribe to the `ApplicationView.VisibleBoundsChanged` event. You can do this for example in your `App.xaml.cs` constructor:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += OnVisibleBoundsChanged;
```

You hide the status bar with the `StatusBar.GetForCurrentView()` instance.

**OnVisibleBoundsChanged** method:

```
private async void OnVisibleBoundsChanged(ApplicationView sender, object args)
{
    var currentView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if (currentView.Orientation == ApplicationViewOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ShowAsync();
    }
    else if (currentView.Orientation == ApplicationViewOrientation.Landscape)
    {
        await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
    }
}
```